# How to make a Dynamic Accordion (WP/bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

How to make a dynamic accordion with WP content?

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">  
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <?php the_content();?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Only first panel works properly.

Comment: Is this code inside of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)?

Comment: `<?php the_content();?>` can you show us the html?